# Comparing two sheets with unique column matching

Tags: vba, excel

How do I compare two sheets in Excel of huge dataset in easy way whether VBA or with formulas?

I have two sheets with 10 columns each. Each sheet has B column with unique batch numbers. I want to compare rows with same B column values between the two sheets and if any difference in other 9 columns, copy entire row to another new sheet.

For example:
[image]

Sheet one is master sheet.  Sheets one and two have same names but the ages are different for name *"b"*, so I need name *b* and age in sheet three and the age cell should be in color in sheet 3 because the age is different.

If I have a large number of columns instead of only age its difficult to identify, usually I use `vlookup` on each column by name as unique and use `if` function to check match or not.

Comment: sheet 1 is master sheet and want to check in sheet 2 . if differece found in sheet 2 means copyentire  raw to sheet 3

Comment: Please add an example (preferably using screenshots) clarifying what you exactly want.

Comment: Please add the code or formulas that you have already created in an effort to resolve your task and detail why they are not working for you.

Comment: Do you have Access? I recommend importing or linking to worksheets and then build a Find Unmatched query.

Comment: Access means means !! i cant find option for attach excel , can you please explain about  importing or linking to worksheets and then build a Find Unmatched query

Comment: as per attached jpg can you please explain above mention query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the code given below.

**Prerequisites:**
1) Code assumes that there are three sheets in the workbook named Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3

2) Sheet1 and Sheet2 have 10 columns each with same headers.

The code below compare the data on Sheet2 with data on Sheet1 based on column B i.e. if a value from column B on Sheet2 is found in column B of Sheet1, the code will compare the data for all the columns of both the sheets and if the data doesn't match or different, the data will be copied to the Sheet3.

```
Sub CompareAndCopyUnMatchedData()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim x, y, z, dict1
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim str As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
ws3.Cells.Clear
ws1.Range("A1:J1").Copy ws3.Range("A1")
x = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
y = ws2.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value
Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    dict1.Item(x(i, 2)) = x(i, 1) & "," & x(i, 2) & "," & x(i, 3) & "," & x(i, 4) & "," & x(i, 5) & "," & x(i, 6) & "," & x(i, 7) & "," & x(i, 8) & "," & x(i, 9) & "," & x(i, 10)
Next i
For i = 2 To UBound(y, 1)
    If dict1.exists(y(i, 2)) Then
        If dict1.Item(y(i, 2)) <> y(i, 1) & "," & y(i, 2) & "," & y(i, 3) & "," & y(i, 4) & "," & y(i, 5) & "," & y(i, 6) & "," & y(i, 7) & "," & y(i, 8) & "," & y(i, 9) & "," & y(i, 10) Then
            str = y(i, 1) & "," & y(i, 2) & "," & y(i, 3) & "," & y(i, 4) & "," & y(i, 5) & "," & y(i, 6) & "," & y(i, 7) & "," & y(i, 8) & "," & y(i, 9) & "," & y(i, 10)
            z = Split(str, ",")
            ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Resize(1, 10).Value = z
        End If
    End If
Next i
Set dict1 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
If you are interested to highlight the cell on Sheet2 which doesn't match with the corresponding cell on Sheet1, you can achieve this with the conditional formatting.
To do so, select the whole data on Sheet2 starting from cell A1 and make a New Rule for conditional formatting using the formula given below and set the format as per your choice.
As a result say Sheet2!E10 doesn't match with Sheet1!E10 then Sheet2!E10 will be highlighted or formatted as per the format you set in the conditional formatting.

Formula to be used for conditional formatting is as below...

```
=A1<>Sheet1!A1
```

Comment: thnxx alot excel master, instead of increase in column from 10  to 12 is it ok that ws1.Range("A1:L1")

Comment: Do you mean if you have 12 columns instead of 10? If so, you will also need to increase the array elements below in the code following the pattern like x(i,11), x(i,12), y(i,11) and y(i,12) wherever you find them.

Comment: thankss all guys it work well !! the another matter is what ever not matching is comes in sheet 3 and is there any other way to identify which cell changed , as if i need complete raw thats fine but also need to know which all cell changed , just have cell color  or something else

Comment: @safwan, Subodh Tiwari already gave you the answer to your _original_ question, so you should take your time to mark it as accepted. New issues are most likely to arise along the implementation of a correct answer in a "real" code, but that shouldn't be the cause of what's been called "chameleon questions" that keep changing to follw coder changing needs. _New_ issues deserve _new_ questions along with true coding efforts on the asker part

Comment: @user3598756 well Noted and sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @Tiwari thanxx alot for your answer and everything works great .i just want to make clarify for above answer =A1<>Sheet1!A1 .its a great option but what i can see is the formula doing is checking cell by cell in sheets which matching or not .so that if two sheets are same but not in correct order means it says not matching even if filter by alphabets  to make it correct order also if there have count difference means it shows not match .

Comment: @Tiwari Really what i need is same like above vba codes . Code gives answer in sheet 3 which is not match based on b column and give complete raws what i need .and in that raw in sheet 3 i also need to know which cell get difference .